# I want to do a comparison with a one-line text file in Windows command prompt

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

To do this in BASH is simple:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "3" > text.file
foo=$(<text.file)
if [ $foo -eq 3 ]; then
echo "bar"
fi
```

Returns `bar`.

Windows, however, will not cooperate.

```
> ECHO "3" > test.file

> SET /p foo= < test.file

> ECHO %foo%
"3"

> IF %foo% equ 3 ECHO bar

> IF NOT %foo% equ 3 ECHO bar
bar
```

I am mystified, and I really need to get this to work. I hope I haven't done something really dumb and elementary, but I fear I have.

Answer (score 0):

As you wrote it with quotes to test.file, you need to surround 3 with quote marks to do the comparison:

```
ECHO "3" > test.file
SET /p foo= < test.file
ECHO %foo%
IF %foo% equ "3" ECHO bar
```

If you want to parse %foo% as an integer to do other operations, use the `set` command with the `/a` argument:

```
> SET /a foo=%foo%
> IF %foo% equ 3 ECHO bar
bar
```

EDIT: I see that you are trying to learn batch while having some experience in linux shells, however MS Batch is really limited, to have a complete shell you should look at [PowerShell](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_PowerShell).

Answer (score 0):

Since you are `ECHO`-ing `"3"` literally, including the quotes, you are actually comparing `"3"` with `3`, which will of course fail. So:

- either type `(ECHO 3) > test.file`, so your comparison `IF %foo% equ 3 ECHO bar` succeeds (this is a numeric comparison here),
- or keep `(ECHO "3") > test.file`, but compare `IF %foo% equ "3" ECHO bar` (note that this constitutes a string comparison due to the `""`, );

Note that I put the `ECHO` commands into parenthesis `()`, because otherwise a trailing space (the one before the redirection mark `>`) will be written to `test.file` as well.

Comment: Thanks for your help. The first bullet works, but the second doesn't because it is actually writing `"3"` to the file. I hate windows.

Comment: For me the second bullet works as well -- note the modified `%foo% equ "3"` expression of the comparison...